# Is URL encoding guarranteed to output printable characters only?

Tags: url, web, character-encoding, special-characters, binary-files

I refer to the URL encoding used in [Burp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FMdEGDShmw) and in the [browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530173/why-browsers-encode-url-in-this-form)

Is URL encoding guaranteed to output printable characters only?

Comment: *Is URL encoding guaranteed to output printable characters only?* Not printable only, but non-special (each char which may be potentially treated as those which have special meaning is replaced). And of course, this is one of the goals of encoding.

Comment: So is printable the subset of non-special or vice versa?

Comment: Some special are printable (for example, `:` and `/`), and they are encoded because they may be used as special.